# counter-example to holomorphic transformations of harmonic functions?

Tags: harmonic-functions, holomorphic-functions

I've been taught in class that if $\phi(x,y)$ is a harmonic function and $f(z)$ is a holomorphic function viewed as a function $\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ then $\phi \circ f$ is also a harmonic function.

My question is how is that possible considering the following example:

> We can consider solutions on the upper half-plane with boundary
>   conditions: $\phi(x,0)=0$.
>
> We then take a holomorphic function mapping the  the interior of the
>   unit circle to the upper half-plane (say a möbius transformation).
>   Since the unit circle is mapped to the boundary of the plane,
>   $\phi\circ f$ is harmonic on the unit disk with bundary zero
>   everywhere.
>
> By the maximum modulus principle, $\phi\circ f=0$ everywhere in the
>   unit disk. but $\phi(x,y)=y$ is a harmonic function with the required
>   boundary conditions that doesn't satisfy this equality.

How to resolve this apparent discrepancy?

Answer (score 3):

Note that boundary of upper half plane is not just $x$-axis, $\infty$ is also a boundary point.

Under the biholomorphism between unit disc and upper half plane, unit circle is mapped to boundary of upper half plane i.e. $x$-axis $\cup${$\infty$}. Hence boundary condition you have given is not on every point of boundary. If you give same condition at $\infty$ then by Maximum modulus principle for unbounded domain, $\phi =0$ everywhere.

Comment: But then if I compose the biholomorphism with my harmonic example, wouldn't that create discontinuous boundary conditions on the circle? Isn't that a problem?

Comment: I said If you give same condition at $\infty$ (i.e $\phi$ vanishes at $\infty$) then after composing with biholomorphism you get vanishing condition on boundary of circle which is continuous boundary condition.

Comment: I understand. But what if I were to give a different boundary condition at infinity?

Comment: If you give different boundary condition at infinity, then you cannot apply Maximum Modulus principle on unit circle to complsed map.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why not? Or how the composition might look like on the unit disk? Thanks for all the help so far.

Comment: After composition, map on unit circle vanish everywhere except at a point which is image of infinity under biholomorphism. Hence map will look like constant multiple of characteristic function of point corresponding to infinity.